# Loop through database fields PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an election system and I am having difficulty solving a problem. Following is how my application looks like.   [image]

At the moment I get these results by adding the query multiple times on my php file. (for example run it where RaceID = 9, RaceID = 10 .........)
I am sure there should be a way of reading the RaceID as an array or some other way and get the results that way. Since these are JOIN tables I am also looking for a way of retrieving the RaceName (Presidential Names, Justice Supreme Court ... etc) and MainRaceName(Titles with red, blue, gray) as well. I hope I am making some sense so far...
Following is my code for

```
<!-- MAIN ELECTION TICKET  MainID loop should control this -->
<div class="panel panel-red margin-bottom-40">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h2 class="panel-title"> <strong>REPUBLICAN NATIONAL</strong>  </h2>
</div>

<!-- End then SUB ELECTION TICKET    RaceID loop should control this section-->
<h3 style="background-color:#f5f5f5; margin:30px; padding:5px; font-weight:Bold ">Presidential Race  </h3>


<!-- Finally Results section ELECTION RESULTS -->
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Candidate</th>
        <th>Votes</th>
        <th>%</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- This area gets the sum of the votes for a specific RaceID -->
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(CandidateVotes) AS value_sum FROM candidates WHERE RaceID =9');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $sum = $row['value_sum'];
    ?>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT candidates.CandidateName, candidates.CandidateVotes, candidates.Party, mainrace.MainRaceName, race.RaceName, candidates.win
                                        FROM candidates
                                        JOIN race ON race.RaceID = candidates.RaceID
                                        JOIN mainrace ON mainrace.MainID = candidates.MainID
                                        WHERE candidates.RaceID = 9";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    for($i=0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++){
        ?>

        <tr>
            <!--Show winner Icon if the win field is selected as 1 from database -->
            <td width="5px">
                <?php if ($row['win']==1)
                {

                    echo "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-check\"></span>";
                }

                else
                {
                    echo "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked\" style=\"color:#cccccc\"></span>";
                }
                ?>


            </td>

            <td><?php if ($row['win']==1){
                    echo "<strong>";
                    echo $row['CandidateName'];
                    echo "</strong>";
                }
                else {
                    echo $row['CandidateName'];
                }

                ?>
            </td>

            <td width="20%"><?php echo $row['CandidateVotes']; ?></td>
            <td width="30%"><?php
                if ($row['CandidateVotes']>0){
                    echo number_format((float)(($row['CandidateVotes']/$sum)*100), 2, '.', ''). ' %';
                }

                else{
                    echo "N/A";
                }
                ?>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>Total Votes:</strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $sum ?></strong></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

I really appreciate if you can provide some samples (loops) how I can resolve this problem. Your help is much appreciated. Sincerely,

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations I will change my code to PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pull down everything you need in one query.

In order to sum up votes by candidate, you need to make sure you `GROUP BY` the candidate name.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(candidates.CandidateVotes) AS value_sum,
  candidates.CandidateName, 
  candidates.Party,
  mainrace.MainRaceName,
  race.RaceName,
  candidates.win
FROM candidates
JOIN race 
  ON race.RaceID = candidates.RaceID
JOIN mainrace
  ON mainrace.MainID = candidates.MainID
WHERE candidates.RaceID = :raceId
GROUP BY candidates.CandidateName
```

Comment: Thanks David. I will try this query and see the results. It makes sense.